# Is there a LINQ method to join/concat an unknown number of lists?

Tags: c#, linq, list, .net-4.0

I have an object that contains a list of child objects, each of which in turn contains a list of children, and so on. Using that first generation of children only, I want to combine all those lists as cleanly and cheaply as possible. I know I can do something like

```
    public List<T> UnifiedListOfTChildren<T>() 
    {
        List<T> newlist = new List<T>();
        foreach (childThing in myChildren)
        {
            newlist = newlist.Concat<T>(childThing.TChildren);
        }
        return newlist;
    }
```

but is there a more elegant, less expensive LINQ method I'm missing?

**EDIT** If you've landed at this question the same way I did and are new to SelectMany, I strongly recommend [this visual explanation](http://www.codethinked.com/a-visual-look-at-the-linq-selectmany-operator) of how to use it. Comes up near the top in google results currently, but is worth skipping straight to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newList = myChildren.SelectMany(c => c.TChildren);
```

Comment: Was confused until you added .TChildren. Thank you, I didn't know SelectMany at all. Unbelievably useful.

Comment: Sometimes I wish SO would allow for follow-up/related questions... Can I combine SelectMany with an OfType sort of implementation, where the lambda can use the derived type's properties?

Comment: @downwitch - `SelectMany` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use `OfType` on the returned sequence.

Comment: thanks, I get that... I guess I'm asking a separate question then. I will try to come up with a way to formulate it better.